# php - File Upload returns blank page

Tags: php, fileinfo

I wrote the following code that should validate an image uploaded by a user. However, when the code is run, it returns a blank page. Here my code:

**HTML** (`<form>` headline):

```
<form class="registerbodysections" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php/registrationForm.php">
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$confirmemail = $_POST['confirmemail'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
$birthmonth = $POST['birthmonth'];
$birthyear = $_POST['birthyear'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$picture = $_FILES['picture'];
$picturelocation = "../img/uploads/'$email'/picture/'$picture[\'type\']";

echo var_dump($picture); //for testing purposes, but does not get executed

function imageFormatCheck ($fileMime) {
    $datatypes = array(
    'image/jpg',
    'image/gif',
    'image/png',
    'image/jpeg'
    );

    foreach($datatypes as $datatype) {
        if ($fileMime !== $datatype) {
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkFileType() {
    if(imageFormatCheck($fileMime)) {
        header('Location: http://google.com');
        exit();
    } else {
        header('Location: http://facebook.com');   
        exit();
    }
}

function moveFile() {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $picturelocation)) {
        header('Location: http://google.com');
        exit();
    } else {
        header('Location: http://facebook.com');
        exit();
    }   
}


if(count($picture)) {

    $tmpName = $picture['tmp_name']; //when I var_dump $picture I receive a single array, not a double array as often seen
    $fInfo = $finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $fileMime = finfo_file($fInfo, $tmpName);
    $finfo_close($fInfo);

    checkFileType();
    moveFile();

}

$userDataArray = array(
    $firstname,
    $lastname,
    $birthday,
    $birthmonth,
    $birthyear,
    $location,
    $picturelocation
);

?>
```

I added the headers for testing purposes. However, none of these ever get executed. Instead, as mentioned above, a blank page is displayed every time. The HTML `<form>` elements are correct that's why I didn't include them here. Any ideas where the problem could be? Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:** the directory `$picturelocation` doesn't actually exist. Does `move_uploaded_file()` maybe create this dynamically if it doesn't exist? Couldn't find anything on this in the documentation.

Comment: what is the output of $userDataArray? I am specifically interested for output of $picturelocation variable.

Comment: try adding `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` above everything on your page. You may have an error.

Comment: @Rasclatt Thanks for you reply. Just did so but the page still stays blank.

Comment: hard to say; can't see if the input has the right name attribute for it. Blank page usually means a syntax error. You running this from where? local/hosted?

Comment: @satroy Did you mean $picture? The output is array(5) { ["name"]=> string(23) "IMG-20150531-WA0008.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpwFtPsv" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(344860) }

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I thought so too. The name attributes from the <form>-Tag are correct I checked them at least 5 times. The webpage is also displayed correctly before the submit button is clicked.

Comment: output of $picturelocation="../img/uploads/'$email'/picture/'$picture[\'type\']"; ?

Comment: @satroy Ugh... thats empty. Suspect a quotation error. Do you maybe see where I went wrong there? Can't see any mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_FILES); die();` at the top of your PHP file?

Comment: Problem may be at quotation mark, please try to use this:

$picturelocation="img/uploads/".$email."/picture/".$picture['type'];

Comment: @satroy Yes, right may be that issue.

Comment: @MoneyIsAMotivation just a sidenote about the many questions asked. People may be inclined to submit more answers for your past questions, by not accepting the ones given to you that may have solved your past coding issues. Ticking the checkmark next to answers given, will mark it as solved. Just in case you didn't know how Stack rolls ;-)

Comment: I deleted my answer. No sense having it in there. It won't serve anyone. I've typed all that up for nothing, only to have another answer upvoted with what I already said.

Answer (score 1):

Files information are available from the Super global $_FILES.So you can get the information of name,type,size and file from the following list.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
$_FILES['userfile']['type']
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```